# How can I make the SQL join combine both date fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL join - with the issue being the bold section

```
SELECT
    TOP (100) PERCENT [C3 Forecast].Budget_VIEW.Claims,
    [C3 Forecast].Budget_Data_Dan.Budgeted_Amount,
    [C3 Forecast].Budget_VIEW.ClaimOpenDate, 
    [C3 Forecast].Budget_VIEW.Underwriter,
    [C3 Forecast].Budget_VIEW.Agent,
    [C3 Forecast].Budget_VIEW.Category,
    [C3 Forecast].Budget_VIEW.ClientServiceType, 
    [C3 Forecast].Budget_VIEW.RiskStatus,
    [C3 Forecast].Budget_VIEW.AssistanceStatus
FROM
    [C3 Forecast].Budget_Data_Dan
    FULL OUTER JOIN [C3 Forecast].Budget_VIEW
            ON [C3 Forecast].Budget_Data_Dan.Insurer_Underwriter = [C3 Forecast].Budget_VIEW.Underwriter
            AND [C3 Forecast].Budget_Data_Dan.Agent = [C3 Forecast].Budget_VIEW.Agent
            AND [C3 Forecast].Budget_Data_Dan.Day = [C3 Forecast].Budget_VIEW.ClaimOpenDate
ORDER BY [C3 Forecast].Budget_VIEW.ClaimOpenDate
```

And the key part is that the `ClaimOpenDate` has dates that go up from Jan 2015 to June 2016 while the Day has dates that run from Jan 2016 to Apr 2019. At present the join is picking up `ClaimOpenDates` but not combining that with the day data so that it's showing a lot of `Null` values.

What am I missing so that I get a full run of months from `Jan 2015` to `Apr 2019`

Thanks
Dan

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain the problem.  You can probably simplify it as well.

Comment: Please read [Tips for asking a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/2835541).

Comment: Hi Gordon, How do I do that if I have data dumps from Excel?

Comment: Why top 100 percent? Is this going to be a view? If so I would warn you that nesting views will cause some really awful performance.

Comment: It is a view but it doesn't have to be TOP 100 PERCENT - can i remove that to get the same return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can COALESCE() `ClaimOpenDate` and `Day` in the ORDER BY.

You can also do this in your SELECT list if you want the Non-Null value to always appear in a certain column.   It's not clear from your question.

Comment: Hi Tab,

I want the non-null value to always be returned with a date in the ClaimOpencolumn - so i need each row to show a date even if other columns return null values

Comment: Then my answer says it:   Use Coalesce on the two columns and alias it as `ClaimOpenDate`

Comment: and how exactly would I go about doing that? 

Sorry this has been frustrating me all day and I don't really understand what I'm doing

Comment: Why then!   allow me to refer you to Stack Overflow's shiny new documentation page:    http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/3234/coalesce/11102/coalesce-basic-example#t=201607271400515397321    Do you also not know how to alias a column in a select list?

Comment: I know how to do an alias but never heard of this Coalesce term